# What is meaning of 'set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "m")' in CMake Tutorial?

Tags: cmake

I am learning CMake with [CMake Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html) and found something which is not clear for me:

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "m")
```

So what is the `CheckSymbolExists`? Is it a function or a lib?
What's meaning of the "m"? Does it mean a lib name or some flag?

I had tried to read through cmake documents, but I just don't understand.
Please somebody help me to understand these.

Comment: "i had tried to read the describe through cmake documents,but i just don't understand" - What **exactly** you don't understand in the documentation for [CheckSymbolExists](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckSymbolExists.html) module? It has a description of `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES` variable: "a list of libraries to add to the link command."

Comment: thx for your reedit, thx very much, and i am understood what is CheckSymbolExists,it a moudle cmake support.yesterday i just don't know CheckSymbolExists is a function or anything else, now i am clear for that.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "m")` does not work if you are using Microsoft Visual Studio toolchain with CMake. MSVC does not have `m.lib`. Just omit that statement: `if(NOT MSVC) set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES m) endif()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, `set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "m")` includes the math library. You do the same on the command-line like this: `gcc test.c -lm` which includes the library libm.so/.dll

`CheckSymbolExists` is a CMake Module which provides more functionality. You can include it with `include(CheckSymbolExists)`
After this you can use the function `check_symbol_exists(...)` in CMake to check the availability of symbols in header files.

The exact example from the tutorial:
`check_symbol_exists(log "math.h" HAVE_LOG)` checks if the header file math.h has a symbol (can be a function, constant or whatever) which is called log. If there is one, the CMake Variable HAVE_LOG is set to 1, otherwise set to 0.

Comment: thx for your reponse,and your detailed explaination, i am clearly with this issue. sorry my reputation is less than 15, i can't vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

The document said, if my understanding is correct, this module will check if a symbol can be correctly linked when it saw a symbol that is not a enum, type or intrinsic.

So in that snippet, when the first runs of `check_symbol_exists` didn't define the two cache variable, it will check if it had missed an required lib, and retry.